# width and height in style doesn't work as I'm expected

Tags: css

I am writing a webpage , and I want to left part is nav page and right part is content page;

and I create a index.html , give a 100vw and 100 vh to container div label;

however when I look the page, the page is displayed not as I expected;

Anyone can help me understand why ?

I have read css width/height definition, can't figure it out by myself.
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <% include('./easyui.art') %>
    <title>测试用例管理系统</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="easyui-layout" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh">
      <div
        data-options="region:'west', href:'/feature/nav'"
        split="true"
        title="特性列表"
        style="width: 20%; height: 100%"
      >
      <% include('./nav.art') %>
      </div>
      <div
        id="content"
        class="easyui-tabs"
        region="center"
        style="width: 80%; height: 100%; padding: 1px"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try styling body as `min-height: 100vh and min-width: 100vw` and then give div with class easyui-layout height:100% and width:100%

Answer (score 1):

1. You posted ASP or Node inclusions `<% ... %>` which makes it impossible for other to answer to you faster because you didn't provide simple valid HTML reproducing the issue
2. I created [this pen](https://codepen.io/artemiusgreat/pen/abJaeZY) and tried to add as much comments as possible explaining the styles. The main idea is that if you want some elements on the page to take 100% of the height, all parent elements must have height = 100%, so in your case you need to set all HTML tags in the hierarchy to `height: 100vh` starting from the `html` and `body`. You don't have styles for the last two tags.
3. By default, `div` has `display: block` styles and this kind of element will not adjust to `height: 100%`. What you need to do instead is to either use `height: 100vh` on all elements or make all elements `display: flex` and `flex-grow: 1` to auto populate available area on the screen.

Comment: thank you very much `!!! your solution works, I need learn about how 'display' control display behaviours

Comment: after your help, I have learned history of css layout, and I totally understand what you said now, thank you.